# File permissions in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

Is there any software that can be installed in Windows XP to set file permissions for guest accounts?

So that they would have to input a valid administrator password first before they can access the file?

I've seen a feature like this in Ubuntu, wherein even the administrator has to input the password over and over just to access a certain drive. But I need it in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah mate,  it's part of the filesystem "NTFS" mentioned by Dan, which comes with Windows XP.

In Windows Explorer, right click on the file/folder you wish to protect from guests, and select "Properties", then use the "Security"(1) tab to modify the permissions. You will probably want to put the "Guests" group in there, and deny them Read access. This will take priority over any allow permissions inherited by the folder, if you want this to propagate into all subfolders, you can use "Advanced" button, and the "Replace all existing inheritable.." checkbox.

This will prevent any user with a Guest account from reading the directory or file.

(1) If you can't see the "Permissions" tab, you will have to disable "Simple Folder Sharing" via, the Windows Explorer window -> "Tools" menu, "Folder Options", right at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it per file, but Windows XP Pro allows you to 'encrypt' folders, whereby you will need a password to access them.

You can find instructions [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000705.htm).

Therre are different instructions for XP Home and XP Pro. Also, your hard-drive must be formatted as NTFS for this to work.

Comment: do you know any techniques so that a guest account cannot access a folder?Encryption is not a solution because I want to protect php files.

Comment: Please elaborate. What about these php files do you want to protect that would preclude encryption?