# files with hidden attribute in xp and folder options

Tags: windows-xp

As an admin, can I set rules to the folder options so that it cannot be accessible in any other accounts. Please help, where do I access such options and how do I do it?
I'm asking this so that I could hide the php files and executable files I wish to hide and to ensure that nobody gets to set the options wherein you can see the files with the hidden attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are advanced [NTFS permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/111168/file-permissions-in-xp/111197#111197) dealing with attributes...(1)

However, I think you just want to "not allow" any account that isn't you. So, modify the folder permissions, (see link above) and remove all accounts except yours(2), This will prevent others from seeing your data.

If another user is an administrator, they can still "Take Ownership" of the folder and change the permissions, so this will only work if you are the only administrator, or you trust them.

(1): Attributes is a Keyword in NTFS, it refers to Read Only or Hidden files etc..

(2): Unless you need the webserver to access the php? (in which case you might need to add either the IIS_WPG or the IUSR_MACHINE or whatever account you have set for the web process)